# is it possible to animate molecule rotation using for loop in pymol?

Tags: python, pymol

Is it possible to animate a molecule in pymol with several rotate commands using a for loop?
or do i have to use moviemaking to do this?

I tried this to animate the molecule

```
for angle in range(0,360,20):
  cmd.rotate('x', angle)
  time.sleep(5)
```

but the script took unusually long to load and I think I only saw the end result (=molecule rotated in 360 degrees) as opposed to each step. How can I display the result of each rotate command?

Comment: are you sure of for angle in range(0,360,20): instead of for i in [i for i in range(0,360, 20)] and cmd.rotate( 'x', angle ) instead of cmd.rotate( 'x', 20)

Comment: both cases work with me